How to factor orthogonal matrices in determinant calculations for the spectral theorem proof?
I'm struggling to understand the following lemma used to prove the spectral theorem.
Namely, that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $Q$ orthogonal, $QAQ^T$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$.
In the proof I wrote down from lecture it does the following manipulation which I'm struggling to justify namely going $det(QAQ^T - \lambda I) = det(Q(A-\lambda I)Q^T)$. How do we get the right hand side of this?

if $QAQ^T v = \lambda v,$  multiply on left by $Q^T$  for $AQ^T v = \lambda Q^T v$   so $A(Q^T v)  = \lambda (Q^T v).$
